# How to reduce the precision of calculations in Matlab Simulink Model to a specific decimal digit?

Tags: matlab, settings, microcontroller, precision, simulink

I want to execute the model in Simulink in reduced precision, i.e. each calculation should be precise to a specific decimal place(say 4th decimal place; 0.0001) instead of 14th digit , which is default in Matlab. Many people wants to reduce a specific variable to lower precision and solutions are available to this. But I need to reduce overall precision. This is to test whether we can get the desired result in not so precise Microcontroller.
May be a setting in Simulink will do this, but I couldn't find it.
Thanks in advance !!

Comment: MATLAB usually is using floating-point variables (double precision). Are you looking for fixed-point maybe?

Comment: Not exactly. I need to reduce the decimal place to which the Matlab calculates the correct value. I am aware of the Fixed point Designer of Matlab, but I think it won't be of much use in my case.

Comment: This is the purpose of the [Fixed-Point Designer](http://www.mathworks.com/products/fixed-point-designer/) (which is for MATLAB, Simulink and Stateflow).

Answer (score 1):

I know about `digits` function in MATLAB, so if you have model main computations makes in `MATLAB function` Block you can try this, but this not be really what you want.

Looks like we can't control Simulink precision by our hands in simple way, but I find two interesting methods:

1. Go to *Configuration parameters/Hardware Implementation* and choose here microcontroller you need. If you can't find it in the list, choose *Custom* and set needed parameters.
2. Second way: if you have [Fixed Point Designer Toolbox](http://www.mathworks.com/products/fixed-point-designer/index.html?s_tid=0313_new_product) try it. I read description - it looks like a tool you need!

And while I was writing this answer I thought about one more thing - you can set **tolerance** for *variable step Solver* in *Configuration parameters*. Yep all number still be the double, but maybe it can helps!

Comment: I am not sure how specifying the Microcontroller in the 'Configuration parameter' settings will affect the model or output of model. Because I tried simulating with 16bit MC, but the output performance remained the same. May be you can shed some light on the limitations of this setting.

Comment: Thanks Mikhail_Sam. Finally I got know what exactly I needed !! I needed to simply convert the Floating point model to fixed point. I did it using Fixed point tool. I am not sure if it is different from Fixed point Designer !! I followed the following procedure: mathworks.com/help/releases/R2014b/fixedpoint/ug/… (available only for licensed users)

Comment: hmm really. Now I read my answer with the clear view and can't find any reason why i wrote this about microcontroller parameters - it will affect to calculation speed, not the tolerance. 
about fixed point toolboxex - I really never used it, so can't answer are they the same things or not. anyway I hope my answer was helpful :)

Comment: I just read at official website - It looks like it's the same things!

Comment: Yes actually they look same !! Thanks Anyways :)

Comment: :) by the way it's a good practice to accept answers. It helps other to see that this problem already solved. Post your answer (as you give solution in comments) or accept mine.